# using bash script on csv - awk and for loop

Tags: bash, loops, csv, for-loop, awk

I have csv file for every day in a month, and the csv file has global point data. I am trying to crop each csv based on latitudinal and longitudinal extents, and export those csvs. Here is what I tried for 5 days in a month.

```
for f in ./VBD_npp_d20190[1-5]*.csv; do 
    awk '{for(i=$4>=3.070359 && i=$4<=40.926137 && i=$5>=107.159444 && i=$5<=128.204291){printf "%s ",$i;} print ""}' "$f" > "$f".new;
done
```

This dd not work. `$4` and `$5` columns have the latitudes and longitudes listed.

Please advise where I am going wrong.

Thanks,

Tilo

Comment: `crop each csv based on latitudinal and longitudinal extents` - what does that mean? What operation is "crop" or "crop"ing? What does mean "based"? If you post excerpt of example input file and expected output you want to have, you will receive help _a lot_ faster..

Comment: 'Crop' here means selecting the points in the csv based on the specified latitudinal and longitudinal extent. The csv has points covering the whole globe.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do it with a "for" ? Interesting approach, but not what I'd have ever come up with. Much easier to us one (or more if statements)

pseudo code

```
{
    if ($4 > minLat && $4 < maxLat && $5 > minLon && $5 < maxLon)
    {
        print
    }
}
```

edit: in fact looks like you might have just a typo `for` instead of `if`? (not quite, you'd remove the redundant `i=` bits and change the print

```
for f in ./VBD_npp_d20190[1-5]*.csv; do 
    # TODO: Modify the print to use $4 (and $5 ?) instead of $i
    awk '{if($4>=3.070359 && $4<=40.926137 && $5>=107.159444 && $5<=128.204291){printf "%s ",$i;} print ""}' "$f" > "$f".new;
done
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I think it has to be a 'for loop' because the csv is of all days in a month, and the for loop has to go through each csv, 'select' the points within the specified latitudinal and longitudinal extent, and create a new output csv.

Comment: You know `awk` runs the "program" for each line of the file right? The whole way you think a for loop works is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This finally worked -

for i in ./VBD_npp_d201901*_global*.csv;do o=`basename $i global_noaa_ops_v23.csv`china_noaa_ops_v23.csv; head -1 $i > $o; awk -F, '{if ($4>=3.07 && $4<=40.93 && $5>=107.16 && $5<=128.20) print ;}' $i>> $o;done